# Matching new lines not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match this text in JavaScript:

```
HEADER
abc1234 blah blah
FOOTER
```

Using

```
(?s)HEADER.*?\w{3}\d{4}[\w ]+.*?FOOTER
```

But it isn't matching.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Would you please not ask such crap question? Your regex won't even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?s)` (DOTALL flag) is not recognized in Javascript regular expression.

Workaround for that I use is using `[\s\S]` instead of `.` to match any character including newlines.

```
/HEADER[\s\S]*?\w{3}\d{4}[\w ]+[\s\S]*?FOOTER/
```

[image]